# How to create new column dynamically in pandas like we do in pyspark withColumn

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

```
from statistics import mean
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df["A"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
df["B"] = ["Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "May", "May", "May", "May"]
df["C"] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 50, 60]
df1 = df.groupby(["A","B"]).agg(mean_err=("C", mean)).reset_index()

df1["threshold"] = df1["A"] * df1["mean_err"]
```

Instead of the last line of code, how can I do it as in Pyspark .withColumn() ?

[image]

This code wont work. I would like to create new column by using output of operation on the fly similarly like we do in Pyspark withColumn method.

Can anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: there is no sample data. but I can reply you like this to make you understand.
df  has three columns "A", "B", "C" which have all numeric values. want to groupby based on A & B, then agg func on C , then the want to create new column which will have the value out of agg func and A coulmn. But this I want to do with continuation of the code without any assignment operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Option 1: [`DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)

```
(df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False)
   .agg(mean_err=('C', 'mean'))
   .eval('threshold = A * mean_err'))
```

#### Option 2: [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
(df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False)
   .agg(mean_err=('C', 'mean'))
   .assign(threshold=lambda x: x['A'] * x['mean_err']))
```

---

```
   A    B  mean_err  threshold
0  1  Feb      10.0       10.0
1  2  Feb      20.0       40.0
2  3  Feb      30.0       90.0
3  4  May      35.0      140.0
4  5  May      50.0      250.0
5  6  May      60.0      360.0
```